# Catch the signal when QWebView was scrolled to the end

Tags: qt, qwebview

When a user scroll with his mouse within a QWebView widget , can i know if he got to the head / end of web contents ?

I may place a QWebView::wheelEvent() inside , but how can i know about the scroll positions ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `scrollPosition` of the page's mainframe:

```
QPoint currentPosition = webView->page()->mainFrame()->scrollPosition();

if (currentPosition.y() == webView->page()->mainFrame()->scrollBarMinimum(Qt::Vertical))
   qDebug() << "Head of contents";
if (currentPosition.y() == webView->page()->mainFrame()->scrollBarMaximum(Qt::Vertical))
   qDebug() << "End of contents";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when searching for an actual *signal* when the scroll position was changed.

There is the `QWebPage::scrollRequested` signal which can be used. The [documentation says](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwebpage.html#scrollRequested) *This signal is emitted whenever the content given by rectToScroll needs to be scrolled dx and dy downwards **and no view was set.***, however the last part is wrong, the signal is actually always emitted.

I [contributed](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/101276/) a fix for this to Qt, so this will probably be corrected as soon as the docs are updated.

---

(original post following)

QWebView doesn't provide this because WebKit manages the scroll-area.

I ended up extending `paintEvent` to check the scroll position there, and emit a signal when it has changed.

PyQt code which emits a `scroll_pos_changed` signal with a percentage:

```
class WebView(QWebView):

    scroll_pos_changed = pyqtSignal(int, int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._scroll_pos = (-1, -1)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        """Extend paintEvent to emit a signal if the scroll position changed.

        This is a bit of a hack: We listen to repaint requests here, in the
        hope a repaint will always be requested when scrolling, and if the
        scroll position actually changed, we emit a signal..
        """
        frame = self.page_.mainFrame()
        new_pos = (frame.scrollBarValue(Qt.Horizontal),
                   frame.scrollBarValue(Qt.Vertical))
        if self._scroll_pos != new_pos:
            self._scroll_pos = new_pos
            m = (frame.scrollBarMaximum(Qt.Horizontal),
                 frame.scrollBarMaximum(Qt.Vertical))
            perc = (round(100 * new_pos[0] / m[0]) if m[0] != 0 else 0,
                    round(100 * new_pos[1] / m[1]) if m[1] != 0 else 0)
            self.scroll_pos_changed.emit(*perc)
        # Let superclass handle the event
        return super().paintEvent(e)
```